# Pointer type vs value type in golang

Tags: go, pointers

Well, I understand what pointer type and value types are in golang and how go internally infer the type for the developer.

But upon reading the post I'm lost
[https://dave.cheney.net/tag/receivers#:~:text=You%20can%20declare%20a%20method,derived%20pointer%20type%2C%20*T%20](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/receivers#:%7E:text=You%20can%20declare%20a%20method,derived%20pointer%20type%2C%20*T%20).

I'm lost. because I don't understand what the post is looking to explain if the point is to tell that Struct should be a pointer type then I don't understand the purpose of using a counter package as an example.

Somewhere I think the post is trying to tell that maybe using the stats as value will get the copy of the counter value but I'm not sure I'm able to derive anything from it on how it can go wrong or what the "whoops" thing here as per the post

Comment: this is not a duplicate question if someone cares to because the stats example is not setting any value it's doing a `Get` call.

Comment: The post talks about good practice for attaching a method to a structure. The correct way is to use a pointer. In some cases, it is necessary to attach a method to the value, as in the case of enums: https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/golang-enum

Comment: Agreed but I would like to understand what is whoops in that post.especially since its a Get call.

Comment: Any value receiver method would copy the embedded Mutex, and ["a Mutex must not be copied after first use."](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex)